# Running Quartz scheduler immediately Java

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to use Quartz scheduler to start new job immediately that will run only once, the job is not being triggered and not getting any exceptions.

Here is the code:

```
public void startRecipeUpdateJob(Ingredients ingredient) {
        try {

            JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
            jobDataMap.put(RecipeMessages.INGREDIENT_TEXT, ingredient);

            // specify the job' s details..
            JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(RecipesUpdateJob.class).setJobData(jobDataMap).build();

            // specify the running period of the job
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().startNow().build();
            SchedulerFactory schFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            Scheduler sch = schFactory.getScheduler();
            sch.start();
            sch.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

            logger.info("Scheduler scheduled job: " + RecipesUpdateJob.class.getClass());

            Thread.sleep(1000L);

            sch.shutdown(false);

        } catch (SchedulerException | InterruptedException e) {
            logger.info("Scheduler Stopped running: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This is the job class:

```
public class RecipesUpdateJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        JobDataMap map = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();

        Ingredients ingredients = (Ingredients) map.get(RecipeMessages.INGREDIENT_TEXT);

        RecipeHelperTwo recipeHelper = new RecipeHelperTwo();
        recipeHelper.updateRecipesCaloriesByIngredient(ingredients);
    }

}
```

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: what is the value of RecipeMessages.INGREDIENT_TEXT ?

Comment: Do you see any logging from Quartz in console? can you paste them here?
Also did you try increasing the sleep time to large number and see what happens?